# Write date/time value to registry

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, registry

What's the best data type and/or format to write and read a date and time value in the Windows Registry?

I'm using C++ with MFC and working with CTime and CTimeSpan objects, but I feel comfortable using the CRT library as well.

My understanding is that to correctly represent a time value, a 64-bit integer should be used.  That precludes using MFC methods such as [WinAppEx::WriteInt()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983542.aspx).

For readability and debugging purposes, I would have liked to use the CTime::FormatGmt() method to write a string to the registry and then read and parse it later, but the lack of a MSVC runtime implementation of strptime() prevents easy parsing on read.  While I could implement strptime(), I'm hoping for a lighter-weight solution.

I have not explored the COleDateTime classes yet.

Thanks in advance, this is my first StackOverflow question.

Comment: You've left out an important piece of information.  How precise do you need the time to be for your application?  That really governs the solution you need.   Days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds?

Comment: Accuracy to the minute.  I don't really need per-second or greater resolution.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [CTime::GetTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s7y67z7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), and store the returned 64-bit integer into registry. When loading pass the same integer to `CTime` constructor.

You may also consider using [time functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4c8f33%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

When serializing a time or timespan, I usually

1. Make sure that whatever value I have is UTC.
2. If not in UTC, then convert to UTC.
3. Convert the UTC value to a FILETIME value.
4. Serialize the FILETIME value.

Works for me.

Comment: Thank you!  I wound up creating a _time64_t value from the CTime object and writing a QWORD entry to the registry.  Should I edit my question to include code?  Or post my own answer?

Answer (score 0):

`COleDateTime` classes are based on doubles where the integer part stands for year/month/day and the fractional part stands for hour/minute/second.

If you cast a `COleDateTime` to a double and multiply by `24 * 60` you get a DWORD that represents the number of minutes since 1899-12-30. You can easily store this DWORD in the registry and later make the inverse conversion back to a `COleDateTime`.

Comment: Thank you.  I was able to use the 64-bit _time64_t type and store it in the registry as a QWORD.  Seemed cleaner than writing two DWORD values.